# sender as in C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

```
private void RectangleTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     RedRectangle.Fill.Opacity = 1.0;
     GreenRectangle.Fill.Opacity = 1.0;
     BlueRectangle.Fill.Opacity = 1.0;
     YellowRectangle.Fill.Opacity = 1.0;

     var rectangle =sender as Rectangle;
     if (rectangle != null)
     {
         rectangle.Fill.Opacity =0.25;            
     }
}
```

What does the `var rectangle=sender as Rectangle` mean ?

This code works with `var Rectangle=sender as Rectangle` too.

Comment: so you have a working code and wanna know why it works? have you tried to search _as operator in C#_ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `as` operator attempts to convert the parameter to the requested type, returning `null` if the conversion/cast fails. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx))

So the code you provided is checking if `sender` is a `Rectangle` object (or a derived type). It then checks for null before using the converted variable, which is always good practice when using `as`.

Note that the second code just assigns to a different variable name, though using a class name as a variable name is *strongly* discouraged.

Answer (score 5):

An event’s `sender` is just passed to the event handler as an object. Now when that event is raised, you usually know what kind of sender you can expect (since you set up the event handler yourself), but the method still requires an `object` type.

Now the `as` is a type conversion that tries to convert the object into that type, but returns `null` if the type is not compatible. So in this case, you have this:

```
var rectangle = sender as Rectangle;
```

There are two possibilities:

1. `sender` is a type that can be assigned to a `Rectangle`, in which case, `rectangle` will contain a reference to the same object but typed as a `Rectangle` instead of just `object`
2. `sender` is of some other type, in which case `rectangle` will be `null`, which is caught in the following check.

Answer (score 2):

You have some really, really basic concepts you're attempting to understand.  I'll attempt to break the question apart with some clarification and add to the two exceptional answers you've received.

**Cast:**

The conceptual notion of *casting* is incredibly important, as this concept is imperative in modification of your data.  Your specifically asking about:

> **Explicit conversions (casts):** Explicit conversions require a cast operator. Casting is required when information might be lost in the
>   conversion, or when the conversion might not succeed for other
>   reasons.  Typical examples include numeric conversion to a type that
>   has less precision or a smaller range, and conversion of a base-class
>   instance to a derived class.

In your example, your implementing the `as Rectangle`.  For the sake of simplicity I'm going to use an easier data type.  The `as` *cast* when it converts it won't create the following error:

- Invalid Cast Exception

Instead it returns a `null` when it fails, which is a clean way to fail silently.  Which meets particular needs in several instances where you don't want an *Exception* to break your user flow.

**Example (A):**

```
int valid = 0;
string number = valid as string;
```

**Example (B):**

```
string valid = 1;
int number = valid as string;
```

**Example (C):**

```
string valid = "valid";
int? number = valid as int?;
```

All three of those examples are valid, however in *Example (C)* you'll notice two items:

- `int?` - Allows a `null` for an `int`.
- It also isn't breaking your application, as the failed *cast* will return `null`.

The other approach for *casting* would be to apply `(int)` or `(string)` to explicitly force the data to that *type*.  So it will either *succeed* and or *throw exception*.  For example:

**Example (D):**

```
string invalid = "Fail"
int? number = (int?)invalid;
```

That would cause the *Invalid Cast Exception* to be thrown.  *Example (C)* and *Example (D)* are two simple comparisons for the difference between *cast*.

Hopefully this provides better information for you.